# Use Expo only for personal device

Tags: react-native, expo

I built an app with expo and React Native. I don't want to publish it on any app store - just load it on my iPhone. Can I manage that with  a free developer account?
I tried the `expo run:ios` command but it just installs the expo client on the phone.

If this is not possible can I use React Native to do that?

When I developed with Swift I could create a 7 day app and load it on my phone.

Comment: You can install the app only on the Simulator until you get Apple Developer Account.  In some cases, Xcode has more advantages than the Expo ecosystem.